# Old anime type movie or show with the boy and the ghost girl with light white or pinkish hair

Tags: story-identification, anime, ghost

I saw this movie when I was very little and just remembered it now, but I can't find it!

I can barely remember but let me try to explain what I think it's about.
So there's this boy who meets a ghost girl with like light white or pinkish hair and they go into like a ghost world and there's talking cats and stuff like that and I think there's those cat clocks that would have their eyes move side to side and in the end of the movie I think the boy becomes a ghost to be with the ghost girl. This is probably not really how the movie goes but if you know it or think you do please tell me!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  Was it dubbed or subtitled?

Comment: I am actually not sure but I think it was dubbed

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this?

Comment: See if something from here rings a bell: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CuteGhostGirl